# Beats music API play track in mobile browser?

Tags: beatsmusic

I am able to play beats music using the beats API 'play a track' method in desktop browser, but it doesnt work on a mobile.How do I get the music to play in a mobile browser?

is there a way to convert rtmp music type to a mobile friendly format?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the playback engine is only approved for use on desktop browsers.